# Spring & JPA: Sort by value, if null take other value

Tags: sorting, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
Entity  

id | ... | special (int) | default (int) NOT NULL  
-------------------------------------------------
10 | ... | null          | 100  
11 | ... | 85            | 90  
12 | ... | 40            | 80  
13 | ... | null          | 70
```

This should be sorted in spring, to take value of column "special" if not null, and otherwise take value of column "default"

if I sort It with Sort.by("special", "default") it will result in two (imaginary) groups:

```
12  (40)
11  (85)
13  (70)
10  (100)
```

but it sould be:

```
12  (40)
13  (70)
11  (85)
10  (100)
```

tl;dr: how so sort like "if not null, take this, else, take value of different column"

Answer (score -1):

So, essentially you want to `ORDER BY CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special ELSE default END`.

Try `JpaSort.unsafe("CASE WHEN ...")` instead of `Sort.by(...)`, it accepts arbitrary expressions rather than property names.

(BTW `COALESCE(special, default)` will probably also work, but I'm not sure, you'll need to check)